# If V is a vector space with finitely many elements, what can you say about the number of elements in V?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If *V* is a vector space with finitely many elements, what can you say about the number of elements in V?

Does the answer have anything to do the with dimension of the basis for the vector space?

Comment: What does "finite amount" mean

Comment: @RushabhMehta A final amount. I am confused too, because I don't know if it is the same as finite-dimensional.

Comment: @Sam "a vector space which is a finite amount" is not a mathematically meaningful statement.  Could you quote the exact wording that the textbook/teacher used in the question?

Comment: @Sam for example, perhaps the question was "If $V$ is a vector space with finitely many elements..."

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're probably right. I edited the text now.

Comment: Are you working with a specific scalar field? Is it $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or something else?

Comment: @Sam have you heard of "finite fields"?

Comment: @bangs It is not specified in the text, so I assume it is ℝ.

Comment: If it is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ (which is likely unless you are in a higher level abstract/modern algebra course), then what can we say about a vector space that has a non-zero vector in it? We know that if a vector space (with the scalar field $\mathbb{R}$) contains a vector $\vec{x}$, then it contains $a\vec{x}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. If $\vec{x}\neq \vec{0}$, what can we say about the vectors $a\vec{x}$ as $a$ ranges over all real values?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We have not learned about it, but I read about it on my own. I don't quite understand the relation between elements and prime powers.

Comment: @bangs If I get you right, I think it means ax⃗ is linear dependent?

Comment: That is true, but that is not what I was getting at. For a non-zero vector $\vec{x}$ and two different real scalars $a,b$, can $a\vec{x}$ and $b\vec{x}$ be the same?

Comment: @bangs If _a,b_ is different, then _ax⃗_ and _bx⃗_ can't be the same, which means we got different elements..?

Comment: Right. So if we have a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with a non-zero vector $\vec{x}$, then that space must contain $1\vec{x}, 2\vec{x}, 3\vec{x}, \ldots$, and that's infinitely many different vectors. So by contraposition, if $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ which does not contain infinitely many vectors, it can't have any nonzero vectors. 

However, if we have a vector space over a different field instead of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, things can be different.

Comment: @bangs thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean real vector space (meaning a vector space over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$), since more generally a vector space is an object associated with a particular field.

Assuming this is the case, suppose you have a vector $v$ from your finite vector space $V$.  Are there any other vectors that you know must be in $V$?  How many of them are there?  Is it possible that $V$ is empty?